# Div breaks into new row even though width isn't 100%

Tags: html, css

So i have a problem.

I have 2 divs , they should be one next to another.

They are both wrapped with div that has some `max-width : n` .

I put `width: 70%` to first div and `width: 30%` to second div. I expect them to fill 100% of the parent div. Instead second div breaks to new line.

Here's a jsfiddle example.

https://jsfiddle.net/u5aqhvmj/

EDIT: Please people, I'm trying to solve this problem. I know I can use floats but that isn't part of this discussion.

Comment: Ok thank you , I'll go check it out!

I just removed all the whitespace between html tags and it works. Why does this happens? Isn't this some kind of bug? Or is there some good reason behind this behavior ?

Comment: in your css file ... div{float:left}

Comment: @Paran0a This is expected behaviour. `inline-block` gives you the best of both `block` (the ability to set `width`) and `inline` (the ability to flow with `inline` elements). The browser is treating the whitespace in a similar way it would between standard `inline` elements.

Comment: Thank you , I'm satisfied with that answer ! The question is a duplicate of the one you linked.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting **float:left** on both divs

Update:

In your html you have whitespace characters taking up space!
So you have 30% + 70% + space taken up by whitespace characters -> >100% which causes the linebreak

If you write all divs in a single line without space in your fiddle

```
<div class="firstQ"></div><div class="secondQ"></div>
```

there won't be a line break

Comment: Floating elements removes them from the flow and has side effects on the following elements that have to mitigated. It is a really hacky way to solve a very simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without `inline-block` 4px reset hack, you can do this with `flexbox`:

```css
.outer {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;   
}

.first,
.second {
  height: 100px;
}

.first {
  background: red;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 70%;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 70%;
  flex: 1 1 70%;
}
.second {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 30%;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 30%;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="first">
    </div>
    <div class="second">
    </div>
</div>
```